# Historical Human Fecundity info?

Tags: population

I'm looking for information about the number of children a woman has over their life time. I get an average to be 5-7 or 10-12 with 1-2 or ~50% dying pre-puberty.

What I'm looking for now is how those children are spaced between 14 and 55 usually, or rather have been across history, rather than modern times because I know its a bit off in modern times.

Is it more likely that a woman would just go and have 7 children in a row between 14 and 20, or space it out at 1 every other year, or 1 every 4 years? I know that in modern times there seems to be a common trend of a child every 2.5 to every 5 years in smaller families, while in bigger they seem to try to get as many kids as possible early... and often couples do kids at the beginning of a marriage. And I know that there are rarities of 10 and 20 year gaps and some women holding off till their forties.

Has this always been the norm or are these trends the norm throughout history?

Comment: Questions asking for historical facts about the real world are specifically off topic on Worldbuilding. You may have better luck on the [history.se] SE.

Answer (score 3):

This is *extremely* dependent on social conditions and technology.

Modern women in advanced countries have access to reliable contraception, and are not regarded as the property of men, which gives them choice over when they have children, and thus how many. They also have access to advanced medicine, which means they're unlikely to die of pregnancy-related conditions, and few of their children die as infants.

When none of those conditions apply, the number of children women have is largely determined by their ability to avoid becoming pregnant, either by social influence over their husbands or by practising forms of sex that have low risk of pregnancy. There have been low-tech methods of contraception, but they aren't very reliable. Different societies have had quite a lot of variation in the acceptability of pregnancy avoidance, but all of them have been clear that you had to have enough children to keep society growing and when the death rate among infants is 50% or more, that's quite a few pregnancies. And each one presented a real risk of death: if human reproduction was much more dangerous than it is, we would have died out as African homids before we ever invented writing.

Many people don't like to talk about the sexual politics of the past, or aren't aware of them. They were pretty gory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42950/discussion-on-answer-by-john-dallman-historical-human-fecundity-info).

Answer (score 3):

> Has this always been the norm or are these trends the norm throughout
>   history?

The short answer is: it depends on the culture and enviroment of the population.

The long answer...

I think it's somewhat reasonable to believe that humans have always had some limited understanding of human reproduction, and *at least **some** parents* would attempt to plan the births of their offspring.

Of course the factors involved in planning are numerous and environmentally and culturally dependent.

For instance nomadic hunter gatherers living in cold climates, with harsh winters, may try to time births toward the warmer months, when food may be more abundant. This would likely place children about a year, or more, apart.

There are important cultural factors to consider as well. For instance polygamist cultures are likely to have a much higher birth rate per household, simply because multiple women may be impregnated by the same man. Hence you could see siblings that were a few days/weeks apart and very large family units.

If you're asking purely about biological capacity... You're still asking a very complicated question. How often do humans copulate? Of those interactions how many result in pregnancy? Of those pregnancies how many survive to term (both infant and mother)? Are the infants breastfeeding, and if so, for how long? Is the population healthy/well fed enough to support infants and young children?

I think at this point it may be worth pointing out that you can't really separate the biological factors from the cultural and environmental factors. For example, an agricultural population will likely have more food on hand, having more food will likely mean higher survival rates all around. 
Simply put: access to food and water can have a huge impact on fecundity and a population's access to food and water is culturally and environmentally dependent.

So... More or less, some cultures and environments would allow for having lots of children spaced closer in age, while some cultures and environments wouldn't.